# Program to reverse an integer then convert integer to text goes to infinite loop

Tags: javascript

The goal of the program is to first reverse an integer. Then convert integer to text.

```
let list = [
  "zero",
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
  "four",
  "five",
  "six",
  "seven",
  "eight",
  "nine",
];

n = 123;
let rev = 0;

while (n > 0) {
  last_digit = Math.floor(n % 10);
  n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  rev = rev * 10 + last_digit;
}

while (rev > 0) {
  rem = Math.floor(rev % 10);
  n = Math.floor(rev / 10);
  console.log(list[rem]);
}
```

This outputs "one one one one one....." forever. Why is it going to infinite loop? It should not be going into infinite loop.

**Expected output is "one two three" when input is 123.**

```
let list = [
  "zero",
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
  "four",
  "five",
  "six",
  "seven",
  "eight",
  "nine",
];

n = 123;
let rev = 0;

while (n > 0) {
  last_digit = Math.floor(n % 10);
  n = Math.floor(n / 10);
  rev = rev * 10 + last_digit;
}

let r = rev;
while (r > 0) {
  rem = Math.floor(r % 10);
  r = Math.floor(r / 10);
  console.log(list[rem]);
}
```

This code fixes the problem, but I don't understand what's the problem with the first code. It looks something happens with the variable "rev" after the first while loop ends. I'm not sure what.

Comment: `String(123).split("").reverse().join("")` is `"321"`

Comment: on your first code you are not changing rev but your while codition uses rev so that makes it infinite loop just change n to rev  on your second while loop and your code should work

Comment: Also you should be declaring **all** your variables with `let`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let list = [
  "zero",
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
  "four",
  "five",
  "six",
  "seven",
  "eight",
  "nine",
];

function NumberToString(list, num) {
  let myFunc = num => Number(num);
  let intArr = Array.from(String(num), myFunc);
  let str = '';
  intArr && intArr.map((e, i, arr) => {
    str = `${str} ${list[e]}`;

  });
  return str.trimStart();
}
let input = 4528;
let output = NumberToString(list, input);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: How do you mastered writing codes using ES6 concepts like map,arrow functions etc? It's something that has been bugging me for some time.

Comment: You should explain what you changed and why. Code dumps are rarely useful without some sort of commentary.

Comment: @catcactcacted [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is a great place to start. They have wonderful documentation and great examples.